# On what day of the year was the below text message sent?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

༊जन्मदिनको शुभकामना!

Below is a screenshot of the same text, in case it does not display correctly on your device.
[image: screenshot of text message]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess:

> February 21!

This, in Hindi, is

> Happy Birthday.

There is ALSO a special character at the beginning which is

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%BC%8A

This is Dzongkha, as told by the OP, so I looked up

> "bhutan birthday", since Dzongkha is the language of Bhutan. More importantly, as told by the OP, it is only used when addressing the King of Bhutan!

And I found the King of Bhutan's birthday is, the answer:

> February 21

Comment: Not bad, you've got the first step! But the answer is not yet correct.
Once you've found the right answer, you will be certain that you have it.

Comment: Is the screenshot in ANY WAY different from the text in the puzzle?

Comment: No, not at all, it is really just a picture of the same text, for no other purpose than stated. However, as a little hint, I believe with just the screenshot it would be much harder to solve!

Comment: I can't find any meaning for this conspicuous symbol: ༊

Comment: it takes some Googling, but once you have found the meaning of this letter, you will have solved the puzzle!

Comment: I THINK I'VE GOT IT!

Comment: congrats!!! your answer is almost correct!! (and you solved the hard part!)

Comment: the correct answer is 21 February, which is the birthday of the King of Bhutan (the character ༊ is used exclusively when addressing the King of Bhutan in writing: https://r12a.github.io/scripts/tibetan/block )

Comment: can I please have my checkmark now huang yusan?

Comment: @黄雨伞 You can use rot13 to hide the content in your comments so that others don't see it (in this case, the answer to the puzzle). You just rotate the letters 13 characters, so A becomes N, B becomes, O, and so on. To decode it, just reverse the process: N becomes A, O becomes B, etc. Here's an example: Guvf vf na rapbqrq zrffntr.